# AngularJS inject service into multiple controllers

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have defined a service in its own module:

```
angular.module('foteDatasetsService', [])
  .factory('foteAPIservice', function($http) {

    var foteAPI = {};

    foteAPI.getDatasets = function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/datasets?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
      });
    }

    return foteAPI;
  });
```

In another module, (in another file) I have a controller where I'd like to use it:

```
angular.module('foteRequests').controller('foteRequestsController',
  ['$scope', function foteRequestsController($scope, foteAPIservice) {

    //snip other stuff

    $scope.datasets = [];

    foteAPIservice.getDatasets().success(function (response) {
      //Digging into the response to get the relevant data
      $scope.datasets = response;
      console.log(response);
    });

]);
```

I have an init for this module in a file called **init**.js that includes the dependency like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('foteRequests', ['foteDatasetsService']);
```

It doesn't look like it's actually injecting the foteDatasetsService INTO the controller though. If I run the app, I get an error:

```
Cannot call method 'getDatasets' of undefined
```

So if I force the issue by including the foteDatasetsService in in the controller like this:

```
angular.module('foteRequests').controller('foteRequestsController', ['$scope',
'foteDatasetsService', function foteRequestsController($scope, foteAPIservice) {
...
}]);
```

it gives me this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: foteDatasetsServiceProvider <- foteDatasetsService
```

EDIT: I want to be able to inject this service into 3 controllers that will need to get this same info.

Any ideas why the factory is not creating the provider? I'm lost on that one...

Comment: could you create plunkr?

Comment: It's so extremely modularized due to our build system. Most of these snippets are in different files. Creating a plunkr would not be feesible. I apologize. Most examples from the Angular docs show creating the controller in the SAME module as the service. That is not what I want to do.

Comment: but, I threw the project on GitHub. I don't think there's anything in there that I'd get in trouble for posting: https://github.com/nobleach/fote-data-download in the branch called dataset-service

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
angular.module('foteRequests').controller('foteRequestsController',
['$scope', 'foteDatasetsService', function foteRequestsController($scope, foteAPIservice)
{ ... }]);
```

Try this:

```
angular.module('foteRequests').controller('foteRequestsController',
['$scope', 'foteAPIservice', function foteRequestsController($scope, foteAPIservice)
{ ... }]);
```

You already have `injected` the `foteDatasetsService`, now you just want to `inject` the service `foteAPIservice`.

**UPDATE** as  @dtabuenc remarked it would be better not to append `Service` in a `module` name.

Comment: Naming your module `foteDatasetsService` is confusing because it's a module not a service.

Comment: @JimWharton it is my pleasure:-)